# Xcode Repeatedly loses storyboard constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I just can't do this again. I have an extensive storyboard, with hundreds of constraints. Every once in a while, Xcode just decides to lose the autolayout constraints and I wind up having to manually drag every one of them back and recreate the entire thing. I have extensive backups, but restoring from them seems to do nothing to correct the problem. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project. Is there anything that I can do to avoid having to spend a day or two starting almost from scratch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: ya ...its happening in Xcode...I don;t know its some type of bug or what...but it takes its current position automatically after sometime..